# Excel 2013 - Command bars issue

Tags: excel, vba

I have a VB6 Addin DLL which creates a Toolbar buttons (using Commandbar object) in Excel .

Code works fine in Excel 2007 & Excel 2010, But fails in Excel 2013.

## Problem Description

Addin DLL is successfully loaded,Toolbar buttons appear in Excel 2013. But Buttons are unresponsive.clicks have no effect.

please help

Comment: I might guess security settings on the application.

Comment: I had a similar problem when adding 2010 compatibility. I'm not sure if anything has changed w/ 2013, however. Show your code that registers the button click. Also, is your code doing a version check?